# Terminology: Average vs Statistic

Tags: statistics, terminology, average

When is it correct to call a calculation an average and when is it correct to call a calculation a statistic?

I  recall reading something along the lines of: an average is calculated directly from a data set whereas a statistic is calculated from averages. Is there a nice rule similar to this that is correct?

Comment: An average is a statistic, but there are statistics besides averages, such as standard deviation

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Then what determines if something is an average or not?

Comment: I don't expect there to be a rigorous definition.  It is like asking what the difference between a lemma and a theorem is.  The word average seems more likely to be used for several things because of its colloquial linguistic meaning rather than a mathematical one.  There are many different types of averages, or rather "means".  [Read about some on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average).

Comment: Now... colloquially, an average *to me* is a statistic about a random variable or set of data, such that it might be otherwise difficult to distinguish from a randomly selected point in the data in some way.  That is not a rigorous definition, mind you, but it will have things such as standard deviation discarded as being an average while other things like mean or mode are allowed.  Again, there are many different "averages" or "means" that we could talk about, and each has their own particular use with some being more common and useful than others.

Comment: @JMoravitz I like that. An average must be found in the data set whereas a statistic might lie outside the data set? This calls all power means averages and calls standard deviation and skew statistics. This seems elegant.